# Browse the file system on namenode is not working: Hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, namenode

I have installed hadoop-1.2.1.I was able to configure name node and job trakcer , both are up and running.
However when i am trying to click on the link "Browse the file system". i am automatically being redirected to "http://0.0.0.0:50070/browseDirectory.jsp?".
Could you please help me here.
PFB my configuration files:

HDFS-SITE.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property> 
<name>dfs.replication</name> 
<value>1</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.permission</name> 
<value>false</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
<value>C:/cygwin64/home/hadoop-dir/datadir</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.name.dir</name> 
<value>C:/cygwin64/home/hadoop-dir/namedir</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->


<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property> 
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
<value>localhost:50001</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why did you put `C:/cygwin64` `dfs.data.dir` and `dfs.name.dir`?

Comment: Earlier i used /home/hadoop-dir/datadir and it gave me some configuration error , so i replaced it with full path

Comment: can you copy data from your local using `-put` or `-copyFromLocal`?